# mamp pro htaccess rewriteRule not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp-pro

i have already search for a long time and i could not figure our why Rewrite Rule is not working. i want to translate this url

> http://localhost/uniwood/template-allgemein.html?postname=kontakt&pageid=27

to

> http://localhost/postname/kontakt.html

here the code in the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^postname/([^/]*)\.html$ /uniwood/template-allgemein.html?postname=$1&pageid=27 [L]
```

I'am using locally on my machine the mamp pro webserver and checked that AllowOverride is on "all".

I do not get any mistakes! Also no error logs!

thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no its only this lines

Comment: I also tested it at another server and it also not working

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser to test this and what is the exact error

Comment: the links to open the url looks that: <a href='template-allgemein.html?postname=kontakt&pageid=27'>test click</a>

Comment: and there is no error! also no error in the mamp log file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /template-allgemein\.html\?postname=([^\s&]+)&pageid=27 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /postname/%1.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^postname/[^.]+)\.html$ /template-allgemein.html?postname=$1&pageid=27 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now i get the path of the installation directory of the the mamp in the url http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/postname/kontakt.html

Comment: is there a bracket missing in the last line?

Comment: I have updated the rules. Try updated ones and make sure they are in root .htaccess