# Rewrite Rules Not Working in MAMP Pro Development Environment for Production Images

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp-pro

When working on a project, I would like to use the online images, so I don't have to download e.g. all images (as described [here](https://css-tricks.com/develop-locally-use-images-production/)).

To achieve this, I wrote a view lines in my `.htaccess`-file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8890
RewriteRule ^wp/media/.+    https://www.example.com:443%{REQUEST_URI}

</IfModule>
```

According to [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) this should convert an image url from:

```
https://example.localhost:8890/wp/media/27442.jpg
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/wp/media/27442.jpg
```

**Context:**

- MacBook Pro
- OS X Catalina 10.15.2
- MAMP Pro 5.5.1
- WordPress 5.3.2
- example.localhost:8890 (SSL) up and running
- local website is working fine

**What I already tried/verified/adjusted:**

- [How to get htaccess to work on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp)
- [mamp pro htaccess rewriteRule not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580088/mamp-pro-htaccess-rewriterule-not-working)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346778/rewrite-rule-to-load-images-from-production-does-nothing?rq=1
- The `.htaccess` is being executed. When entering garbage, I got a error 500
- Changed `httpd.conf` accordingly

Am I missing something? What else could prevent this from working?

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Does the redirect not happen at all, does it go to a wrong URL, do you get errors …

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had another `.htaccess`-file inside the `wp`-folder, because I moved the WordPress installation into its own directory (see [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change)). When moving the rules into this inner `.htaccess`-file, it started working immediately.